# SQL Query filter by status

Tags: sql

I had the following sort of table:

```
id      status      iteration  
----    -------     ----------  
1111    1           1  
1111    3           2  
1111    4           3  
1112    1           1  
1113    1           1  
1113    4           2  
1114    1           1
```

the problem i am facing is trying to make a query with the IDs whose status is 1 or 3. If the status is ever 4, we should remove that id from the query.

I had made the following query but i can only seem to get the results which have been 1 or 3. if the same id has a status of 4, i can't filter it out.

```
Select id,status, iteration
from table
WHERE status IN (1,3) ;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Why are you selecting 1-3 when you could just NOT and select status 4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT id, status, iteration
FROM table
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table WHERE status=4)
```

...which just excludes the 4's.  If you truly just want 1's and 3's and exclude everything else:

```
SELECT id, status, iteration
FROM table
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table WHERE status NOT IN (1, 3))
```

thanks to @sstan for catching some bad logic in the second example!

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the expected result:

```
select *
from table t1
where status in (1,3)
and not EXISTS
(
    select * from table t2 where t2.id = t1.id and t2.status = 4
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The query may need to be changed depending on what Sql version you are looking for but if I understand what you are asking you only expect to get back the 1112 and the 1114 records based on what you described.  If that is correct here is my version of your query request.

select Id, Status, Iteration 
from table
where Id not in (select Id from table where Status = 4 )